# Heatmap with Plotly on Timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, plotly, heatmap

I have

```
X_reduced_df[Heatmetrics]=
omicron delta   copy_number_1_a_liter   copy_number_1_b_liter   copy_number_1_c_liter   copy_number_2_a_liter   copy_number_2_b_liter   copy_number_2_c_liter
0   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
1   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
3   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
4   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
393 0.000   0.000   38000.000   22725.000   52250000.000    27750.000   31250.000   36500000.000
394 0.000   0.000   38000.000   41500.000   28000000.000    38500.000   26750.000   29250000.000
395 0.000   0.000   49000.000   80500.000   30250000.000    59000.000   81500.000   40500000.000
396 0.000   0.000   15400.000   11500.000   3600000.000 20775.000   11350.000   6675000.000
397 0.000   0.000   35000.000   33500.000   35500000.000    30000.000   28750.000   37250000.000
```

here the first column is the index and not omicron.
Next, I try

```
df = X_reduced_df[Heatmetrics].to_numpy()    
dates= X_reduced_df['EXTRACTION_DATE_SAMPLE'].to_numpy()
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
        z=df,
        x= dates,
        y=Heatmetrics,
        colorscale='Viridis'))

fig.update_layout(
    title='BWB Heatmap',
   xaxis_nticks=50
)

fig.show()
```

where

```
Heatmetrics=[
 'omicron',
 'delta',
 'copy_number_1_a_liter',
 'copy_number_1_b_liter',
 'copy_number_1_c_liter',
 'copy_number_2_a_liter',
 'copy_number_2_b_liter',
 'copy_number_2_c_liter']
```

and

```
X_reduced_df['EXTRACTION_DATE_SAMPLE']=
EXTRACTION_DATE_SAMPLE
2021-07-13   2021-07-13
2021-07-18   2021-07-18
2021-07-21   2021-07-21
2021-07-24   2021-07-24
2021-07-27   2021-07-27
                ...    
2022-11-17   2022-11-17
2022-11-17   2022-11-17
2022-11-20   2022-11-20
2022-11-20   2022-11-20
2022-11-20   2022-11-20
Name: EXTRACTION_DATE_SAMPLE, Length: 398, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

now, I get
[image]

this does not show the whole possible number of dates

I want something like here from plotly documentation

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

programmers = ['Alex','Nicole','Sara','Etienne','Chelsea','Jody','Marianne']

base = datetime.datetime.today()
dates = base - np.arange(180) * datetime.timedelta(days=1)
z = np.random.poisson(size=(len(programmers), len(dates)))

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
        z=z,
        x=dates,
        y=programmers,
        colorscale='Viridis'))

fig.update_layout(
    title='GitHub commits per day',
    xaxis_nticks=40)

fig.show()
```

which yields[image]

and is much more accurate.

How can I get there? what is wrong with my code? I have made all necessary imports(

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objects as go
```

) and tried both in the same notebook in this sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the example data is 496 rows by 8 columns (excluding the date); if the x-axis is a date, it should be 8 rows by 496 columns. An array transformation is therefore required. I have created a heatmap with similar sample data, but with the date interval on the x-axis set to 1 month intervals. If you choose a different date interval, please refer to [this reference](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/#configuring-tick-labels).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'EXTRACTION_DATE_SAMPLE': pd.date_range('2021-07-13', '2022-11-20', freq='1d'),
                  'omicron': np.random.rand(496),
                   'delta': np.random.rand(496),
                   'copy_number_1_a_liter': np.random.rand(496),
                   'copy_number_1_b_liter': np.random.rand(496),
                   'copy_number_1_c_liter': np.random.rand(496),
                   'copy_number_2_a_liter': np.random.rand(496),
                   'copy_number_2_b_liter': np.random.rand(496),
                   'copy_number_2_c_liter': np.random.rand(496)
                  })

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
        z=df[df.columns[1:]].values.reshape(8,496),
        x=df['EXTRACTION_DATE_SAMPLE'],
        y=df.columns[1:],
        colorscale='Viridis'
))

fig.update_layout(
    title='BWB Heatmap',
    #xaxis_nticks=50
)
fig.update_xaxes(type='date', dtick='M1')

fig.show()
```

[image]